# Is there any shapefile (or other format) of Russia's time zones after 2014 changes?

Tags: shapefile, data, time, russia

According to [for example Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Time_in_Russia#2014_zone_boundary_changes), Russia changed its time zone boundaries in 2014, moving areas between existing zones and defining new ones for the Crimea area.

Is there any shapefile or other geometric data available somwhere which is up-to-date enough to reflect these changes? The only shapefile of Russia's time zones [that I could find so far](http://efele.net/maps/tz/russia/) was last updated in April 2013 which was before the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there seems to be no such source... the closest I could get to is using textual sources describing the time zone changes in detail for different admin areas and then composing the shapefiles myself from available shapefiles of the Russian admin areas, e.g. with QGIS or ArcMap.

The best text sources describing the changes that I could find are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia ([Oblast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblast) level)
- http://www.worldtimezone.com/dst_news/dst_news_russia66.html ([Raion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raion) level)

Shapefiles of Russian admin areas (I don't know their accuracy though) can be downloaded from 
http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata .

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into open street map (https://www.openstreetmap.org)? As far as I understand, they have the most updated vector data (boundaries etc) as it is continuously done on a voluntary basis from around the world.

Comment: ... but no time zone information.

Comment: Well, [this Wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:timezone) suggests that there might be some, but still I would not know how to extract this for a specific country...